# Edit div property React

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm trying to edit div class when i click on button like this with ReactJS Typescript :
[image]
[image]

I need to delete button and remove height property on 2 class.
I need to delete gradient div too.

This is my actual code :

```js
                          <section className="FlexContainer-text">
                            <p>
                              {tutorial.message ||
                                tutorial.messages.map((n) => (
                                  <span>
                                    <div className="conseil-card-pack" **onClick={changedivhere}**>
                                      {n.message}
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="more-button">
                                      <div className="more-button-text">
                                        Afficher tous les messages
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                  </span>
                                ))}
                            </p>
                            <div className="conseil-card-title">
                              Titre : {tutorial.title}
                              {tutorial.isPack ? " Pack oui" : " Pack non"}
                            </div>
                          </section>
```

```css
.conseil-cardactive {
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px #00000014;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 16px/22px Poppins;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 8px;
  height: 136px;
}

.conseil-cardactive svg {
  float: left;
}

.conseil-card {
  background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 12px #00000014;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #212529;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  text-align: left;
  font: normal normal normal 16px/22px Poppins;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 8px;
  height: 136px;
}

.conseil-card p {
  text-align: left;
}

.conseil-card svg {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.conseil-card-title {
  color: #8d9899;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.conseil-card-pack {
  text-align: left;
}

.conseil-card-pack::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 760px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 107px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: transparent
    linear-gradient(180deg, #ffffff00 0%, #ffffffcd 48%, #ffffff 100%) 0% 0%
    no-repeat padding-box;
}
```

I'm new on ReactJS... I dont know how can I create a typescript function to edit my className with onClick because i have to many class to change (or property)..

Comment: Usually in React click functions aren't changing classes; they are changing _state_. The JSX reacts to changes in the state. So your function could change `isMessageCollapsed` from true to false, and then the button's visibility, message CSS classes, etc. would be conditional on that.

Comment: I see what you say, but I cant make an if on return. How can I display "if isMessageCollapsed, display button, css class... else if false, display another class without button" ?

Comment: Here's a resource on conditional JSX rendering: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.

For classes, the classnames library is popular for this use case. https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#usage-with-reactjs